# Resolution does not get back to Full HD in windows VDI

Tags: resolution, vmware

I am connecting to a windows VDI, from ubuntu with VMWare Horizon, I have a lot of lag while sharing screen in teams.

Previously I hadn't that problem and the resolution was smaller, then, I changed to 4K and Windows changed automatically to 4K (restarting system).

The problem is, when I try a FullHD resolution (ubuntu) now, Windows VDI does not get back to FullHD as expected after a VDI reboot. I need some way to make the VDI go to FullHD again, to not to have lag in teams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seams there are some (most) cases in which Windows VDI fails to adapt to the native resolution. So, considering I also have monitors of smaller resolution, I solved it by using the "View" menu option "Full Screen All Monitors", in that case Windows VDI mimics easily the native "ubuntu" resolutions.
[image]